# How to replace MobileBy.IosUIAutomation because it was deprecated in previous versions?

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automation, appium

I'm working on an automation project, I need to find an element depending on the text it contains inside an IOS app, but **MobileBy.IosUIAutomation** no longer works with iOS 10 and higher, how can I replace this piece of code to make it do the same functionality.

`

```
listItem = element.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(
"new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(" + "new UiSelector().text(\"" + itemText + "\"));
```

`

Does anyone know of a replacement for **MobileBy.IosUIAutomation** or how it could perform the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

`MobileBy` is replaced by `AppiumBy`

for example

```
AppiumBy.accessibilityId("username")
AppiumBy.xpath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XCUITest` driver now for Automating iOS application.

So instead of `iOSUiAutomation` locator strategy, you can now use `NS predicate string` or `iOS Class chain` locator strategies.

Check out my blog on [different locator strategies in Appium](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/locators-in-appium) where you can get more details about the above mentioned locator strategies.

In your example, if you use `NS predicate string`, the locator will be,

```
listItem = element.findElement (MobileBy.iOSNsPredicateString ("label == \"" + itemText + "\"));
```

**Note:**
In iOS, you now don't need to do `scrollIntoView` because with `XCUITest` driver, it is able to find all the elements on the screen, even those which are not visible on the viewport.