I updated the appium and appium-python-client after writing a Python script with appium for mobile web testing and it suddenly gets an error
In this sauce,
    import logging
    from appium import webdriver
    from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import subprocess
    import time
    import random

    # Logging configuration
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    def check_airplane_mode(device_id):
        # Check current airplane mode status
        logging.debug(f"Checking airplane mode status for device {device_id}")
        command = ["adb", "-s", device_id, "shell", "settings", "get", "global", "airplane_mode_on"]
        result = subprocess.check_output(command).decode().strip()
        logging.debug(f"Airplane mode status: {result}")
        return int(result)

    def setup_settings_driver(device_id):
        # Set up driver for the Settings app
        settings_caps = {
            'platformName': 'Android',
            'deviceName': device_id,
            'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
            'appPackage': 'com.android.settings',
            'appActivity': '.Settings',
            'noReset': True,
            'newCommandTimeout': 200
        }
        logging.debug("Setting up driver for device settings")
        return webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', settings_caps)

    def toggle_airplane_mode(driver):
        # Toggle airplane mode
        logging.debug("Toggling airplane mode")
        driver.start_activity('com.android.settings', '.Settings')
        connections = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().text("Connections")')))
        connections.click()
        airplane_mode = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().text("Airplane mode")')))
        airplane_mode.click()
        toggle_switch = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.ID, 'com.android.settings:id/switch_widget')))
        toggle_switch.click()
        time.sleep(2)

    def setup_chrome_driver(device_id):
        # Set up Chrome driver
        chrome_caps = {
            'platformName': 'Android',
            'deviceName': device_id,
            'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
            'browserName': 'Chrome',
            'noReset': True,
            'newCommandTimeout': 200
        }
        logging.debug("Setting up Chrome driver")
        return webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', chrome_caps)

    def random_scroll(driver, min_scroll, max_scroll, min_duration, max_duration):
        width = driver.get_window_size()['width']
        height = driver.get_window_size()['height']
        
        start_x = width // 2  # Start scrolling from the vertical center
        start_y = int(height * 0.8)  # Start scrolling from 80% of screen height
        end_y = int(height * 0.2)  # Scroll down to 20% of screen height

        action = ActionChains(driver)
        # Perform scrolling for a random number of times
        for _ in range(random.randint(min_scroll, max_scroll)):
            # Perform actions to drag from start to end
            action.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body"), start_x, start_y)
            action.click_and_hold()
            action.move_by_offset(0, end_y - start_y)
            action.release()
            action.perform()
            # Wait for a random duration between scrolls
            time.sleep(random.randint(min_duration, max_duration) / 1000)  # Convert to milliseconds for sleep

    def open_chrome_and_search(driver, query):
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        random_scroll(driver, 1, 3, 300, 800)

    def get_connected_devices():
        # Get list of connected devices
        logging.debug("Fetching list of connected devices")
        result = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "devices"]).decode().splitlines()
        devices = [line.split()[0] for line in result if "device" in line and not "devices" in line]
        return devices

    # Check connected devices
    devices = get_connected_devices()
    logging.info(f"Connected devices: {devices}")

    for device_id in devices:
        # Initialize Chrome driver
        # Check airplane mode status
        airplane_mode_status = check_airplane_mode(device_id)
        
        if airplane_mode_status == 1:
            settings_driver = setup_settings_driver(device_id)
            toggle_airplane_mode(settings_driver)
            settings_driver.quit()
            chrome_driver = setup_chrome_driver(device_id)
            open_chrome_and_search(chrome_driver, "test")
            chrome_driver.quit()
            
        elif airplane_mode_status == 0:
            settings_driver = setup_settings_driver(device_id)
            toggle_airplane_mode(setup_settings_driver(device_id))
            settings_driver.quit()

There's an error like this.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pi\\main.py", line 3, in \<module\>

from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium.webdriver.common.mobileby'

I'm sure I installed it properly, and it worked until the update

The appium version is 2.5.2,
Python is 3.12.3,
Appium python client is  4.0.0.

Is there a big change in syntax?
I tried reinstalling python, reinstalling node.js itself and reinstalling Appium, but this error keeps coming up.
Even I change the source code using "by" syntax
    import logging
    from appium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import subprocess
    import time
    import random

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    def check_airplane_mode(device_id):
        # Check airplane mode status for the device
        logging.debug(f"Checking airplane mode status for device {device_id}")
        command = ["adb", "-s", device_id, "shell", "settings", "get", "global", "airplane_mode_on"]
        result = subprocess.check_output(command).decode().strip()
        logging.debug(f"Airplane mode status: {result}")
        return int(result)

    def setup_settings_driver(device_id):
        # Set up driver for the device settings
        settings_caps = {
            'platformName': 'Android',
            'deviceName': device_id,
            'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
            'appPackage': 'com.android.settings',
            'appActivity': '.Settings',
            'noReset': True,
            'newCommandTimeout': 200
        }
        logging.debug("Setting up driver for device settings")
        return webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', settings_caps)

    def toggle_airplane_mode(driver):
        # Toggle airplane mode
        logging.debug("Toggling airplane mode")
        driver.start_activity('com.android.settings', '.Settings')
        connections = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().text("Connections")')))
        connections.click()
        airplane_mode = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().text("Airplane mode")')))
        airplane_mode.click()
        toggle_switch = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'com.android.settings:id/switch_widget')))
        toggle_switch.click()
        time.sleep(2)

    def setup_chrome_driver(device_id):
        # Set up Chrome driver
        chrome_caps = {
            'platformName': 'Android',
            'deviceName': device_id,
            'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
            'browserName': 'Chrome',
            'noReset': True,
            'newCommandTimeout': 200
        }
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', chrome_caps)
            return driver
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(f"Failed to create driver with UiAutomator2: {e}")
            chrome_caps['automationName'] = 'UiAutomator'
            return webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', chrome_caps)

    def random_scroll(driver, min_scroll, max_scroll, min_duration, max_duration):
        # Perform random scrolling on the web page
        width = driver.get_window_size()['width']
        height = driver.get_window_size()['height']

        start_x = width // 2  
        start_y = int(height * 0.8) 
        end_y = int(height * 0.2)
        
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        for _ in range(random.randint(min_scroll, max_scroll)):
            action.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body"), start_x, start_y)
            action.click_and_hold()
            action.move_by_offset(0, end_y - start_y)
            action.release()
            action.perform()
            time.sleep(random.randint(min_duration, max_duration) / 1000)  

    def open_chrome_and_search(driver, query):
        # Open Chrome browser and perform a search
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        time.sleep(2)  
        random_scroll(driver, 1, 3, 300, 800)

    def get_connected_devices():
        # Fetch list of connected devices
        logging.debug("Fetching list of connected devices")
        result = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "devices"]).decode().splitlines()
        devices = [line.split()[0] for line in result if "device" in line and not "devices" in line]
        return devices

    print("Appium version: <Your Appium Version>")

    devices = get_connected_devices()
    logging.info(f"Connected devices: {devices}")

    for device_id in devices:
        # Check airplane mode status and perform actions accordingly
        airplane_mode_status = check_airplane_mode(device_id)

        if airplane_mode_status == 1:
            settings_driver = setup_settings_driver(device_id)
            toggle_airplane_mode(settings_driver)
            settings_driver.quit()
            chrome_driver = setup_chrome_driver(device_id)
            open_chrome_and_search(chrome_driver, "test")
            chrome_driver.quit()
            
        elif airplane_mode_status == 0:
            settings_driver = setup_settings_driver(device_id)
            toggle_airplane_mode(setup_settings_driver(device_id))
            settings_driver.quit()

There's an error like this.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

I've tried this and that, but I keep getting errors.
Did syntax change a lot?
I see other similar examples in Stack Overflow, but it doesn't work even if I try all of them.

from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74350065/how-to-replace-mobileby-iosuiautomation-because-it-was-deprecated-in-previous-ve
